# Does C# Console.Clear() make influence to nodejs spawn?

Tags: c#, node.js, spawn

I try to use NodeJS spawn to run C# exe, following is my JS Code:

```js
const { spawn } = require("node:child_process");
const grep = spawn(
  "D:\\...\\ConsoleApp1.exe"
);
grep.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
grep.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  data = data.toString();
  console.log(data);
});
```

And I try to use `Console.Clear()` in C#:

```cs
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("before in while");
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("in while loop");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

when I directly run C# exe in PowerShell, I got expected output:

```
before in while
in while loop
in while loop
in while loop
in while loop
in while loop
in while loop
in while loop
in while loop
```

But when I run this exe in NodeJS, it was exited immediately:

```
PS D:\Project\PerfMonitor\test> node .\test.js
PS D:\Project\PerfMonitor\test>
```

When I remove `Console.Clear()` in C# code:

```cs
// Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("before in while");
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("in while loop");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

NodeJS can output normally:

```
before in while
in while loop

in while loop

in while loop
```

I also try this with Python 3 subprocess module:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("D:\\TestSpace\\Csharp\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\ConsoleApp1.exe")
```

And the output of is right.

The following are my environment:

- OS: Windows 11 Professional version 22H2
- NodeJS version: v18.12.1
- C# aim framework: net6.0
- Python version: Python 3.11.3

It seems that NodeJS `spawn` will be influenced by C# `Console.Clear()` in some way, what's happened here and how to avoid this issue?